# Get file encoding of a large csv

Tags: php, csv, encoding

I need to determine the character encoding of the contents of a .csv file.

Every snippet that I have seen do this uses `file_get_contents()`, however I can't use that because the file is too large to store in a variable (server memory limit exhausted).

How can I determine the character encoding of a file? Can I just get the first x characters and check them? Would that guarantee that my whole file is that encoding?

Alternatively, can I simply convert the entire csv to UTF-8 without knowing the current file encoding?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php with `FILEINFO_MIME_ENCODING`

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't determine the encoding with just the first x characters. You can guess it, and the guess may be wrong. The file may be UTF-8 but not contain UTF-8 before x characters. If may contain another encoding that is compatible with ASCII, bot only after character x.

No, you can't convert a file without knowing the current file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can go straight to the conversion, as you said, using iconv (http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php#49434)

Answer (score 0):

> *'Pray, Mr. Babbage, if you put into the machine wrong figures, will the right answers come out?' I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.*
>
> —Charles Babbage, 1864.

You have missing metadata and are proposing to put in values whether they are right or not.

Only the author/sender can tell you, perhaps via some standard, specification, convention, agreement or communication. A common method of communication when transferring data via HTTP is the Content-Type header.

Unfortunately, inadequate communication of metadata for text files and streams is too common in our industry. It stems from the 1970s and 80s when text files were converted to the local character encoding upon receipt. That doesn't apply anymore and nothing really took its place.

Non-answer:

- Conversion from ISO-8859-1 will never fail during conversion because it uses all 256 bytes values in any sequence.
- Conversion to any current Unicode encoding (including UTF-8) will never fail because all of them support the whole Unicode character set, and Unicode includes every computerized character you are likely to see today.

But wait, there is more needed metadata in the case of CSV:

- line ending (arguably detectable)
- field separator (arguably detectable)
- quoting scheme, including escaping
- presence of header row
- and, finally, the datatype of each column.

And, keep in mind, if you were to guess any of this, and the data source is updatable, today's guess might not work tomorrow.